# How can one name the array of a return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Not too sure if I'm doing this right. It looks a bit more convoluted than it needs to be. But I am trying to pull a specific piece of data out of a json array. I need several features of this data piece, and then I need to take the `return`, label the `return`, and pass it through a method at the bottom of success call.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ( window.location.href.match(/customer_number/).length > 0) {

    $customer_id = window.location.href.split(/customer_number=/)[1];

    $.ajax({
      url: '/customers/filter.json',
      data: { id: $customer_id },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        response($.map(data, function(row) {
          return {
            value: row.customer.name,
            customer_number: row.customer.customer_number,
            id: row.customer.id,
            name: row.customer.name,
            phone_number: row.customer.phone_number,
            email: row.customer.email,
            service_address: row.customer.service_address,
            service_city: row.customer.service_city,
            service_state: row.customer.service_state,
            service_zip_code: row.customer.service_zip_code,
            billing_adress: row.customer.billing_address,
            billing_city: row.customer.billing_city,
            billing_state: row.customer.billing_state,
            billing_zip_code: row.customer.billing_zip_code,
            primary_contact_name: row.customer.primary_contact ? row.customer.primary_contact.first_name + ' ' + row.customer.primary_contact.last_name : ''
          };
          render_customer(name_of_return);
          //                  ^^ Not sure how to label that return into an object.
        }));
      }
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: What's your goal with the above code?

Comment: It's really hard to follow your explanations, partly because your loose usage of JavaScript terminology. There aren't any arrays in your code and you already have an object. Could you at least post an example of your desired output?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: There's definitely at least one array (the return value of `$.map`, being passed into `response`), and possibly two (if the top level of the JSON data received is an array). But agreed it's really hard to figure out what the code is meant to do, and why naming comes into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the returned object back to `$.map`'s handling of the return values for the iteration function (it builds up those values in an array), and then handing that array into your `response` function. In JavaScript, when you're calling a function (or returning a value out of one), you don't give the arguments / return value names. In the case of arguments, it's entirely positional. (The function definition may assign them names, but you don't when you call them.) In the case of a return value, there is only ever one.

Comment: So you're saying it's over kill to map it after I return an object?

Comment: @Trip: I'm saying names don't come into it vis-a-vis the arguments to functions you're *calling* or function return values. I can't comment on anything else because I don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this? you store the object in a variable and pass it to that function.

```
var yourObject = {
                value: row.customer.name,
                customer_number: row.customer.customer_number,
                id: row.customer.id,
                name: row.customer.name,
                phone_number: row.customer.phone_number,
                email: row.customer.email,
                service_address: row.customer.service_address,
                service_city: row.customer.service_city,
                service_state: row.customer.service_state,
                service_zip_code: row.customer.service_zip_code,
                billing_adress: row.customer.billing_address,
                billing_city: row.customer.billing_city,
                billing_state: row.customer.billing_state,
                billing_zip_code: row.customer.billing_zip_code,
                primary_contact_name: row.customer.primary_contact ? row.customer.primary_contact.first_name + ' ' + row.customer.primary_contact.last_name : ''
              };
    render_customer(yourObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

When ever you return something, the method stops running. You can not run any code after this point.

You should make an array or an object and put all the values you need in there.

You can do that by making an object like this:

```
var return_var = {};
```

And when you want to add stuff to this array just use the object syntax like this:

```
return_var.key = value;
```

Now you can just return or pass the object to a function, and use it like this:

```
alert(array.key);
```

Edit:

I see you actually already have an object, so you can just pass `return` to your `render_customer` function, and use it as I described above.